# How to summarise data over several years into one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` that contains information about businesses. Each row is a business. Column G has the id of the business and columns R and Z (as well as others) have integers telling me different measures of the income. Column A has the year. I want to produce a new dataframe which has only one line per business with the values for the different years combined. Say columns B-Q don't change per year but R and Z do.

To achieve this I am doing `df1.groupby("G", as_index=False)["Z"].sum()` to get the sum incomes from column `Z`.  I would similarly do `df1.groupby("G", as_index=False)["R"].sum()`  and so on.

I would like the final dataframe called `df2` to have one line per business with all the  columns from `df1` which don't change very year and also the new Sum columns.  The following code is my attempt but it isn't right. The problem is that I don't understand how to add the result of groupby to a column.

```
df2['SumZ'] = df.groupby("G")["Z"].sum()
df2['SumR'] = df.groupby("G")["R"].sum()
df2['RZ'] =df2['SumR']/df2['SumZ']
```

One method would be make a new dataframe df2 with a copy of columns B-Q, say and then add those columns to it.

How can one do this?  My attempts to make a new dataframe to then add columns to have failed.

Here is my complete code.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import pandas as pd

inputfile = sys.argv[1]
city = sys.argv[2]
xl = pd.ExcelFile(inputfile)

df1 = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0], skiprows=4,skip_footer=9)   
df1.columns = [chr(65+i) for i in xrange(len(df1.columns))]
df1.replace('*', 3, inplace=True)
df1 = df1.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

for c in ['R', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']:
    df1[c] = df1[c].astype(int)

for c in ['B','E', 'H', 'J', 'O', 'Q', 'S', 'U', 'W', 'Y']:
    df1.pop(c)
print "Read in..."
#Now attempt and fail to make a new dataframe summarized by year    
df2['SumZ'] = df1.groupby("G", as_index=False)["Z"].sum()
df2['SumR'] = df1.groupby("G", as_index=False)["R"].sum()
```

---

This does what I need but seems very ugly.

```
summary_data = df1[['G', 'R','T', 'V', 'X', 'Z']].groupby('G').sum()
constant_data = df1.drop(['R', 'T', 'V', 'X', 'Z'], axis=1).groupby('G').first()
df2 = summary_data.join(constant_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the .agg method on the groupby object. .agg stands for aggregate. You are essentially agreegating the data into one single observation. You can then pass a dictionary of functions to the agg that tells it what to do with each column. So imagine your data frame looked like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'business' : ['business_1', 'business_2', 'business_3', 'usiness_4', 'business_1', 'business_2', 'business_3', 'business_4'], \
               'years' : [2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014], \
               'zip_code' : ['101', '102', '103', '104', '101', '102', '103', '104'], \
               'profit' : [random.randint(1000, 2000) for x in xrange(8)]})
```

Now 'business' is like your id variable, zip_code is your data that do not change, and profit is the thing you want to sum.

You already know what function to use to get the sum, its sum. But you need to write a function to take the only unique value of zip code. You can do something like this:

```
def take_single(series):
    return series.unique()[0]
```

Now create your groupby object, create a dictionary of functions to be executed on each column, and pass that dictioanry to the .agg method (aggregate) like so:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('business') 
function_dict = {'business' : take_single, 'zip_code' : take_single, 'profit' : sum}
df_grouped.agg(function_dict)
```

This gets the result you want I think.

One thing to note is that the series of data which is having an aggregation function passed to it is automatically passed as the first argument of the function. Therefore in take_single function you see an argument called series. But this is argument is automatically passed when .agg is called, so there is no need to specifiy it within the function dictionary.

Sum is a built in function, so no need to write that one separately.

To replicate this, simply create the dictionary with B-Q keys with take_single value, and then R and Z with sum function value. Does that make sense?

Its not easy to understand groupby (for me anyway), but it is verty useful....

Rory