# Understanding groupby and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I'm trying to use pandas on a movie dataset to find the 10 critics with the most reviews, and to list their names in a table with the name of the magazine publication they work for and the dates of their first and last review.

the movie dataset starts as a csv file which in excel looks something like this:

```
critic   fresh    date    publication  title      reviewtext     
r.ebert   fresh   1/2/12   Movie Mag   Toy Story    'blahblah'
n.bob     rotten  4/2/13   Time        Ghostbusters 'blahblah'
r.ebert   rotten  3/31/09  Movie Mag   CasaBlanca   'blahblah'
```

(you can assume that a critic posts reviews at only one magazine/publication)

Then my basic code starts out like this:

```
reviews = pd.read_csv('reviews.csv')
reviews = reviews[~reviews.quote.isnull()]
reviews = reviews[reviews.fresh != 'none']
reviews = reviews[reviews.quote.str.len() > 0]

most_rated = reviews.groupby('critic').size().order(ascending=False)[:30]
print most_rated
output>>>
critic
r.ebert  2
n.bob    1
```

Then I know how to isolate the top ten critics and the number of reviews they've made (shown above), but I'm still not familiar with pandas groupby, and using it seems to get rid of the rest of the columns (and along with it things like publication and dates). When that code runs, it only prints a list of the movie critics and how many reviews they've done, not any of the other column data.

Honestly I'm lost as to how to do it. Do I need to append data from the original reviews back onto my sorted dataframe? Do I need to make a function to apply onto the groupby function? Tips or suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you want to do. But the size() function (not groupby) is what removes most of the columns. The columns (like date) aren't specific to the reviewer so it's not clear what it would mean to append them to the review counts.  But you could do reviews.groupby('critic').date.max() and similar functions to summarize data from other columns.

Comment: you can do `reviews[ reviews.critic.isin( most_rated.index )]` to get the full data frame of most rated critics;

Comment: This question/answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248580/how-to-summarise-data-over-several-years-into-one-dataframe/22250844#22250844

Comment: I have an answer to the question which you deleted, in case you wanted to undelete it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338440/counting-string-values-in-pandas-dataframe-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DanB says, groupby() just splits your DataFrame into groups. Then, you apply some number of functions to each group and pandas will stitch the results together as best it can -- indexed by the original group identifiers. Other than that, as far as I understand, there's no "memory" for what the original group looked like.

Instead, you have to specify what you want to output to contain. There are a few ways to do this -- I'd look into 'agg' and 'apply'. 'Agg' is for functions that return a single value for the whole group, whereas apply is much more flexible.

If you specify what you are looking to do, I can be more helpful. For now, I'll just give you two examples.

1. Suppose you want, for each reviewer, the number of reviews as well as the date of the first and last review and the movies that were reviewed first and last. Since each of these is a single value per group, use 'agg':

`grouped_reviews = reviews.groupby('critic')
grouped.agg('size', {'date': ['first', 'last'], 'title': ['first', 'last']})`

1. Suppose you want to return a dataframe of the first and last review by each reviewer. We can use 'apply', which works with any function that outputs a pandas object. So we'll write a function that takes each group and a dataframe of just the first and last row:

`def get_first_and_last(df):
    return pd.concat((df.iloc[0], df.iloc[-1]), axis = 1,ignore_index = True)
grouped_reviews.apply(get_first_and_last)`

If you are more specific about what you are looking to do, I can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: thank you so much! That helps a lot, especially what exactly the grouped.agg() versus grouped.size() does to the dataset. I do have one last question off of the first example you give. .agg() only takes one argument, so using 'size' inside of it doesn't work (at least not for me). How would you take grouped.agg({'date': ['min', 'max'], 'publication': ['first']} and print a table with the same information BUT only the 10 critics with the most reviews?